# Swift - check if function parameter was passed

Tags: swift, default-parameters

Let's say I have the following function:

```
func update(a a: String? = nil, b: String? = nil) {
    if a.notDefaultValue /* or something like that */ {
        // ...
    }

    if b.notDefaultValue {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And I can call it in those ways (expecting to do as in the comments):

```
update()               // Should do nothing
update(a: nil)         // Should only go into first 'if' statement
update(b: nil)         // Should only go into second 'if' statement
update(a: nil, b: nil) // Should go into both 'if' statements
update(a: "A")         // Should only go into first 'if' statement
update(b: "B")         // Should only go into second 'if' statement
update(a: "A", b: "B") // Should go into both 'if' statements
```

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT:**

The only way I could think of doing this is with method overload, but that is unfeasible when you have many parameters (don't even have to be that many, 4 will already need 17 methods).

Comment: You can simply check if the specified argument has the default value, in your case it is nil.

Comment: But that won't distinguish between `update()` and `update(a: nil)`

Comment: 2^4 is 16, not 17 :)

Comment: Rodrigo, there is no difference to the call flow of the first 4 update() examples. The local values of the a and b arguments within the update function body will be nil whether they were copied in from the caller explicitly or were copied in by the default argument initializer.

Comment: I know, that is my problem, I want those 4 to be different.

Comment: I think you cant. The problem is not the language but the programming logic you applied there.

Answer (score 2):

```
func update(a a: String?, b: String?) {
    if let a = a, b = b  {
        print("a = \(a), b = \(b). a and b are not nil")
    } else if let a = a {
        print("a = \(a). b is nil")
    } else if let b = b {
        print("b = \(b). a is nil")
    } else {
        print("a and b are nil")
    }
}
func update() {
    print("no parameters")
}

update()                //  "no parameters\n"
update(a: nil, b: nil)  //    "a and b are nil\n"
update(a: nil, b: "Y")  // "b = Y. a is nil\n"
update(a: "X", b: nil)  // "a = X. b is nil\n"
update(a: "X", b: "Y")  // "a = X, b = Y. a and b are not nil\n"
```

Comment: That won't distinguish between `update()` and `update(a: nil)`

Comment: I think you can't , if you don't pass any parameters a and b will also be nil

Comment: It would be much easier to pass a Bool value

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm looking for. I want the calls to be like in my question.

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz the trick is not defining = nil otherwise you won't be able to call it without any parameter

Comment: like I added in my question, that is not feasible with many parameters, I'd need `update()`, `update(a a: String?)`, `update(b b: String?)` and `update(a a: String?, b: String?)` just for 2 parameters

Comment: You would need only 2 methods. 1 with parameters and 1 without

Comment: And how do I call `update()`, `update(a: "a")`, `update(b: "b")` and `update(a: "a", "b")` ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you would want to do this, but you can do it in this way:

```
let argumentPlaceholder = "__some_string_value__"

func update(a a: String? = argumentPlaceholder, b: String? = argumentPlaceholder) {
     if a == argumentPlaceholder {
        // Default argument was passed, treat it as nil.
    }

     if b == argumentPlaceholder {
        // Default argument was passed, treat it as nil.
    }
}
```

Comment: As long as the place holder (default argument) is kept private (i.e, unknown to the calling side), you should be pretty confident that the caller did not provide any argument when the parameter equals the placeholder.

Comment: I could do that (but using a GUID to be sure), though that is a bit hacky and wouldn't work very well for other parameters line `Int`.

Answer (score 0):

Also try to write something like this:

```
func hello() {
    print("hello")
}

func hello(name: String) {
    print("hello \(name)")
}

func hello(name: String, last: String) {
    print("hello \(name) \(last)")
}

hello()
hello("arsen")
hello("arsen", last: "gasparyan")
```

It's more functional way

Comment: Like in the end of my question, that is not feasible, if I have 4 parameters it will lead to 17 methods